# <type 'NoneType'> issue when doing math

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code, but when i run it I get type 'NoneType'. I pinpointed to my "summation" variable being the one that has Nonetype, why is that? and how can i change it? I tried making into a float() but it did not work for me. Any insights would be welcome.

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def grades_sum(scores):
    total = 0
    for item in scores:
        total = item + total
    print total

grades_sum(grades)


def grade_average(grades):
    summation = grades_sum(grades)
    average = summation / float(len(grades))
    return average

print grade_average(grades)
```

Comment: grade sum isn't actually returning anything.   it just prints.  so your summation = grades_sum(grades)  causes summation to be assigned to None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `summation` just calls the function, nothing else, so it is equal to a `NoneType` or basically nothing. Change `print total` to `return total` to allow `summation` to be equal to whatever `total` is.

```
def grades_sum(scores):
    total = 0
    for item in scores:
        total = item + total
    return total
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Change the print to a return.

```
def grades_sum(scores):
    total = 0
    for item in scores:
        total = item + total
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define `grades_sum()`, you don't return anything, you just print it.  Change it to this:

```
def grades_sum(scores):
    total = 0
    for item in scores:
        total = item + total
    print total
    return total
```